# tee-chart with Delphi not showing bar graph in 3d

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have a Delphi XE2 program displaying a bar chart, with the 3d effect initially working. Then I added a series for a piechart, and made sure that the orthogonal box is checked under 3d, and under 3d Views I selected "ortho right"

The 3d effect no longer works. Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Comment: You might need to dump all the relevant properties here for people to see

Answer (score 2):

I've added a `TBarSeries` to a new `TChart`.
Adding a `TPieSeries` later, I see the `Aspect.Orthogonal` property changes to `false`.
But I can still force it to `true`:

```
  Chart1.Aspect.Orthogonal:=true;
```

Note a Bar series is drawn using the typical orthogonal axes, while the Pie series doesn't use any axis. So, using both series in the same chart looks weird:

[image]

Comment: I added the line of code provided to set orthogonal to true but it did not help. I deleted the tchart and added a new one, with 2 series like before, and now it works! Something must have been set incorrectly in the chart editor but I have no clue what. Thanks everyone for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the 3d property true at runtime?

```
Chart1.view3d:=true;
```

and so on...

Probably the series that you have added doesn't have the 3d functionality.
Pay attention when you add a chart, you can select 3d series or 2d series as you need.

Comment: to the first responder - I do not know how to print out all the properties. I tried export but it showed nothing useful. I took screen shots but I cannot post them here.

Comment: To 2nd responder, I added that line of code to set view3d to true even though it was already checked on the options tab, but  it is the same problem. So in this case, I had it working with 2 series and changed the 2nd series from piechart to bar graph and never made the piechart active, and the bar graph, though its properties were unchanged, no longer displays in 3d.